# rails newbie - how to change querystring into route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

Am learning rails the way most do, by implementing a blog. I've just put tagging in and have got my article view to the point where it's displaying clickable tags when you display an article. The issue is that the links are coming out like this;

http://localhost:3000/articles?tagged_with=development

I would prefer not to have the querystring, and instead have something like;

http://localhost:3000/articles/tagged_with/development

I can't find anything relevant in the "routes inside out" guide on the rails site (lots of useful stuff in there, just not this!)

Complete code here: 
https://github.com/mikeyhogarth/mikeyblog

Pertinant bits are;

the link in _article.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to tag, articles_path(:tagged_with => tag) %>
```

the articles index controller:

```
def index

 if(params[:tagged_with])
   @tag = params[:tagged_with]
   @articles = Article.tagged_with @tag
 else
   @articles = Article.all
 end

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @articles }
 end
end
```

what is the rails best practice way of doing this? Do I need to implement a "tagged_with" action and create a helper or is there some rails routing magic that can sort this out in a jiffy?

EDIT: Eventually found the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this to your routes (untested):

```
match '/articles/tagged/:tagged_with' => 'articles#index', :as => :tagged_articles
```

Then:

```
link_to(tag, tagged_articles_path(:tagged_with=>"foobar"))
```

Comment: I'll give you the point anyway bud, thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer eventually: I needed a "named route". If anyone else has this question, I just put this in my routes.rb file;

```
match "/articles/tagged_with/:tag" => "articles#index", :as => "articles_tagged_with"
```

then simply relpaced my "link_to" with this;

```
    <%= link_to tag, articles_tagged_with_path(:tag => tag) %>,
```